# Forming C Structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

for small structure sizes ,i am using named tuple and struct.pack in python 2.7 like this

```
 format_="i"
 namedtuple("connections","number")                                      
 connection(number=0)                       
 struct.pack(format_, *connection_tuple)
```

Now i have to frame bigger structures having structure inside structure,we can do by struct.pack but is there any other way we can form the big strucutue data?

Comment: create a class and use it to hold your smaller structs data and operations on it?

Comment: like using ctypes ...?

Comment: when i am trying to send structure with headers added giving following errorTypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ctype structure' objects
my code:
        pkt = self.dstMacAddr + self.srcMacAddr + etherType + <ctype structure object>